# Formatting all drives by booting from a USB stick

Tags: boot, usb, script, formatting

We have a customer that has recently been a victim to an encryption attack.
They now want to switch over to a "linux environment" by reusing their old machines, installing Igel OS and using a Citrix environment.

Their plan is to format all drives currently in those machines first using a USB stick, from which we boot that runs a script to format everything.

I'm experimenting with the steps in a VMWare VM right now. I tried using a FreeDOS image disk and just changing the autoexec.bat but I can't get the VM to boot from that.

Have you ever done anything like this and have any tips? This should require no user input as we are talking 500+ machines and very little time.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Doing it with a VM might not be easy. As you will need to boot each machine either way selecting a wipe all option shouldn't be hard. Regardless there are plenty of tools that provide auto wipe options. If you are going to install another OS anyway why not just include it in the installation process?

Comment: Is the crux of the issue that you are struggling to create a bootable usb stick?

Comment: Seems like the issue resolved itself... The customer now wants to replace all existing clients with new Igels. This seems to be the final decision for now. I won't be investigating this issue any further.